# Optimize a list of inputs as a variable or function in R

Tags: r, performance, optimization, neural-network

I'm trying to automate this one part of my R script, but I can't figure out how. Essentially, I have this code:

```
  currentmatrix <- datas[,,i]
  data <- as.data.frame(currentmatrix)
  #mod #
  colnames(data) <- c("in1","in2","in3","in4","in5","in6", "in7", "in8", "in9", "in10", "out") #change depending on number of inputs and add to nnet training
  
  #mod #
  nnet <- neuralnet(out~in1+in2+in3+in4+in5+in6+in7+in8+in9+in10, data, hidden=hidden, threshold = threshold, stepmax = 10^7,err.fct = "ce",linear.output = F,likelihood = T)
```

Now, where I have `"in1","in2"` etc, I'd like this to be a variable, so that I can simply reference `neuralnet(var,data,hidden=hidden,...)`, instead of typing out the inputs to the function each time I want to change the number of inputs. I'd like, for example, to have a function `f` for which `f(x)` creates `x` strings named `in[x]`, and then I could write
`colnames(data) <- c(f(x))` and `nnet <- neuralnet(out~f_sum,...)` or something similar.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reformulate` which returns a formula object.

```
formula <- reformulate(paste0('in', 1:10), 'out')
formula
#out ~ in1 + in2 + in3 + in4 + in5 + in6 + in7 + in8 + in9 + in10
```

You can also use column names to generate formula.

```
formula <- reformulate(names(data)[1:10], 'out')
```

this can be used in `neuralnet` function.

```
nnet <- neuralnet(formula, data, hidden=hidden, threshold = threshold, 
                   stepmax = 10^7,err.fct = "ce",linear.output = F,likelihood = T)
```

Comment: That works so well for the `neuralnet` input, thank you! Is there something similar that can be done for the `colnames(data)` line? It's completely fine if it's another block of code like above.

Comment: You can use `colnames(data) <- c(paste0('in', 1:10), 'out')`

Comment: It works beautifully, thank you! I need to test it out a bit more but I think this is the solution :).